# Is there a way to break the multicol env within it?

Tags: tables, two-column, multicol, figure-placement

I've been using the multicol package to create two columns. Because the native twocolumn env  can't balance the length of columns. But I'm facing trouble to position my wide tables in it. I used tabularx to make my tables span throughout the text width but now I can't figure out how to place it place it properly within the multicol env. I have also tried the \begin{table*}{h} but the table keeps falling into the next page even though there is sufficient space in the previous page. Is there a way to interrupt multicol and to create one column portion within it? I searched for the solution everywhere but haven't get any yet. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'cp1252'-Western, 'cp1251'-Cyrillic, etc.
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{multicol, blindtext}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx, threeparttable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \blindtext[2]
\begin{itemize}
    \item {\bf Test Case I:} \blindtext
    \begin{table*}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{4 generator system with generating limits and VPL}\
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} \hline
\textbf{Unit} & {${\boldsymbol P}_{i}$${}^{min}$} & {${\boldsymbol P}_{i}$${}^{max}$} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\alphaup}$${}_{i}$} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\betaup}$${}_{i}$} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\gammaup}$${}_{i}$} & {${\boldsymbol e}_{i}$} & {${\boldsymbol f}_{i}$} \\ \hline\hline 
1 & 10 & 55 & 1000.403 & 40.5407 & 0.12951 & 33 & 0.0174 \\ \hline 
2 & 20 & 80 & 950.606 & 39.5804 & 0.10908 & 25 & 0.0178 \\ \hline 
3 & 47 & 120 & 900.705 & 36.5104 & 0.12511 & 32 & 0.0162 \\ \hline 
4 & 20 & 130 & 800.705 & 39.5104 & 0.12111 & 30 & 0.0168 \\ \hline 
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \small \item \raggedleft * Data source: IJERT
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}

\item{\bf Test Case II:} \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide code example (full but minimal examples), then we don't have to guess exactly what you are doing.

Comment: you can use `\begin{table*}` as normal. What did you try?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for looking into the problem. I've attached the code with my question now. Actually I tried the \begin{table*} but the table didn't reside in the page it should be. So pls help me to deal with it.

Comment: you can never use `[h]` with `table*` spanning tables with or without multicol always come at the earliest on the next page.   Also latex has not defined `\bf` by default since 1994, article class adds a definition for compatibility with documents that are older than that

Comment: why `$$` here? `${\boldsymbol P}_{i}$${}^{min}$` that should be `$\boldsymbol {P}_{i}^{\mathrm{min}}$`

Comment: Isn't there any way to bring the table back to the previous page? I wanted to use the twocolumn in documentclass but it can't balance the columns. What should I do to place the table in its actual position in a balanced column manner?

Comment: Actually I've converted a word file into latex. Sorry if there are other syntactical mistakes. But here my focus is to align the table properly in its actual place in a balanced two column text body.